# How to keep Serial number unchanged in HTML Table sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

My Table

```js
$('th').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.toString().localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 23</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After Sorting it displays as:

```
S.No. Name     col 3    col4
2     name 2   data 2   data 23
1     name 1   data 1   data 2
```

I want this:

```
S.No. Name     col 3    col4
1     name 2   data 2   data 23
2     name 1   data 1   data 2
```

The S.No column must always start with 1 but my problem is, it sort the s.no. column too i want that unchanged even after sorting. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks For Help.

Comment: So, do you want the sorted table to be stored in a variable, separately?

Comment: no i want my first column that is S.no will be unchanged even after sorting other columns so that it will always start with 1 and then sequentially.

Comment: try running your for loop from i=1 i.e `(i=1;i<rows.length;i++) `

Comment: it did not work it just ignore first row but not the first column

Comment: It would seem like, from your example, you want to leave the data unchanged and only sort the serials...

Comment: no sorry for that but i want just opposite sort all columns except serial no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line of code 
`$(rows[i]).find('td:first').text(i + 1);` in your for loop before `table.append(rows[i]);`

Also you might want to disable sorting on S.No column if that needs to remain unchanged. Apply the click listener like
`not(:first-child)`

```js
$('th:not(:first-child)').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        $(rows[i]).find('td:first').text(i + 1); //update the s.no td in each sorted row
        table.append(rows[i]);
    }
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.toString().localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 23</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This does not leave it unchanged. This sets the index to i+1. id est 1 2 3 4 5 etc. Original indexes could vary. However, if it works, that's for the best.

Comment: @Attersson It does not change the index. In the for loop , iteration is done on all rows starting from index 0. So if
i == 0 means, that is row 1 and as per his case S.No needs to be shown as 1. Its not setting the index to i+1, its updating the S.No cell in each row when its sorted.

Comment: And this setting is not what the question asked. The question asks to preserve the original S.No. unsorted. They could be 1 10 15 and not necessarily 1 2 3. by using .text(i+1) you do set the text

Comment: In his question, he has clearly mentioned `The S.No column must always start with 1`. Your statement does not match with that.

Comment: 1 10 15 starts with 1 and maintains sorted order. Let's leave it at that. The question is poorly formulated.

Comment: I agree it can be that way too, depending on the use case. But in this case, the S.No column is just used for specifying the row number. If the S.No can be 1,10,15..., in that case the column holds a data of some importance (not the row numbers) and it would be sortable as well

Comment: @Attersson How about my solution?